# Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir './src/functions/.DS_Store' What is this and how to fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
node:internal/fs/utils:351
    throw err;
    ^


Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir './src/functions/.DS_Store'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1532:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/bot.js:43:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  errno: -20,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOTDIR',
  path: './src/functions/.DS_Store'
}
```

part of code which is giving error

```
const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
  const functionFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(`./src/functions/${folder}`)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
  for (const file of functionFiles) require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`);
}
```

I was trying to make Logs function for my Discord bot and saw that nothing is happening and everything broke after writing code, so I removed all files and code from main 'bot.js' file and now it's giving this error

Answer (score 1):

`fs.readdirSync` returns all the contents of a directory including files and not just folders. `.DS_Store` is a special file (not folder) used by Mac to store `Finder` information.

In the sample code you pasted, ensure to check whether the item returned by `readdirSync()` is a directory or not before iterating over the contents in the `for` loop, something like this

```
const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions`).filter(item => item.isDirectory())
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
  // rest of the logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix that I found looks like this

```
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath).filter(file => file !== '.DS_Store');
```

Answer (score -1):

ok so to remove .DS_Store files I just wrote the following line in the terminal and it worked.

Also today I had another error regarding 'fs.readdirSync()' function, said that the provided directory cannot be found so to fix that just give the whole path to your folder/file. ***(For Example, Scroll downwards)***

The line to write in the terminal to remove/delete all .DS_Store files.

> find . -name ".DS_Store" -type f -delete

Example :

***(BEFORE)***

```
const commandsFolder = fs.readdirSync('./Commands');
```

***(AFTER)***

```
const commandsFolder = fs.readdirSync('/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/Commands');
```

Hope it helps :)

sorry for bad english :')

Comment: Don't worry about your English, that's fine. Couldn't say the same about this answer though.